# SQL Logic How to fetch all the column value after a given column value until a specified value is found

Tags: sql

[image]

Hi, In the above table I want to update all the values of the derived columns after a paticular column value in col3  say for example in col3 whenever the value Val1 comes then we have to update values of derived column to val1 and all the next rows to val1  until col3 values is Val2. When col3 value is Val2 then all the columns and it's next values to be updated as null until col3 has val1.

Please help me with the sql logic

Comment: Please add the sample data as text which we can use as opposed to image which we can't. Also I can't see a way of establishing AFTER or any other sequence of events..

Comment: Sorry but whenever I try to paste table it converts into image over here

Comment: Does `col1` uniquely identify the order of your data? and what are you using MySQL or BigQuery?

Comment: Yes you can say that

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL 8.x, we could use a running sum that increased by 1 wherever `col3= val1 or val2` to group the data, then use the conditional max window function within the `nullif` function to get only `val1` and null instead of `val2`. After getting the correct results (using a CTE), use an update with a join to update the table.

```
with cte as
(
  select col1, 
    nullif(max(case when col3 in ('Val1', 'Val2') then col3 else null end) over (partition by grp), 'Val2') der 
  from(
    select *,
    sum(col3 in ('Val1', 'Val2')) over (order by col1) grp
    from table_name
  ) t
)
update table_name tb join cte 
  on tb.col1 = cte.col1
  set derivied_col = cte.der
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XplsZ-DH)

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE your_table t1
SET
    t1.Derived1 = 
        CASE
            WHEN t1.Col3 = 'Val1' THEN 'Val1'
            WHEN t1.Col3 = 'Val2' THEN NULL
            ELSE t1.Derived1
        END,
    t1.Derived2 = 
        CASE
            WHEN t1.Col3 = 'Val1' THEN 'Val1'
            WHEN t1.Col3 = 'Val2' THEN NULL
            ELSE t1.Derived2
        END,
    t1.Derived3 = 
        CASE
            WHEN t1.Col3 = 'Val1' THEN 'Val1'
            WHEN t1.Col3 = 'Val2' THEN NULL
            ELSE t1.Derived3
        END
WHERE 
    t1.Col3 IN ('Val1', 'Val2') OR 
    (t1.Derived1 = 'Val1' OR t1.Derived2 = 'Val1' OR t1.Derived3 = 'Val1')
ORDER BY t1.Col1, t1.Col2;
```

Comment: I want all values in derived column to be updated as Val1 whenever val1 comes  and all it's next values  like if col3 there is val1 then in derived column it should be val 1 and for msg1 and msg2 it will be val1 in derived columns unless and until there is val2 in col3. where there is val2 in col3 then all the next values in the derived column to be updated as null even for message 3 and 4